# Trim zeros from decimal part php

Tags: php, number-formatting

My exact requirement is, if the second decimal of the value is zero,
the value should only have one decimal. For others, it should have two decimal.

```
eg 1. 150.00 to 150.0  
eg 2. 150.10 to 150.1  
eg 3. 150.76 to 150.76
```

What I need to know is whether there is any PHP function to do this.

```
echo floatval("150.00")."<br>";
echo floatval("150.10")."<br>";
echo floatval("150.76")."<br>";
```

The result is as follows:

```
150
150.1
150.76
```

I need to have 150.0 instead of 150. I just need to know if there is any php function. Otherwise I will be able to write code.

Comment: Did you try anything to fulfill your requirement???

Comment: try casting it to floatval() Eg: `$num = floatval(150.10);`

Comment: PS : this may fail for 150.00. Take this into string and check `rtrim()`  function

Comment: seeing the answer you picked clearly shows you don't really know how to describe the problem.

Comment: @hummingBird : may be those who answered understood it better.

Comment: @Thejas: i honestly doubt it - note that they actually corrected their answers in somewhat accordance to my proposal, hence they too noticed the error

Comment: @hummingBird: they corrected for your requirement, not mine. I needed cases of 2 decimals only.

Comment: @thejas: i'm sorry, but you really don't follow. my comment was correcting an error the user did and i clearly described it, along with example. and this was an answer you picked. it doesn't matter whether or not you like it - it doesn't give what you asked for and you picked it. you should have modified your question then. by the way, consider also integer 150. it has no decimals, so by your "exact request", it should have two decimals. hence, number 150 should be translated to 150.00 :)

Comment: @thejas: but ok, i apologize for writing. you're free to pick any answer you like.

Comment: @hummingBird: apologies from me too. What we need is questions and answers that others find helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use substr() function also to remove last char if it is 0. May be the below code will help you

```
function roundit($string)
{
 $string = number_format($string,2);
 if (substr($string, -1, 1) == '0')
 {
  $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
  echo $string;
 }
 else
 echo $string;
}
roundit('150.00');
roundit('150.10');
roundit('150.76');
```

Comment: actually, this doesn't do what op said. he said, "if the second decimal of the value is zero, the value should only have one decimal. For others, it should have two decimal." if I put roundit(152.333332), it will put that same number :). and he clearly said "for others, it should have two decimal." I guess OP doesn't really know what he needs ;)

Comment: in that case he can use number_format() function to get exactly 2 decimals.Updated the answer adding that

Comment: it still doesn't work for e.g. 100.4320 -> it would give 100.432. you should first number_format it and then cut the trailing zero (if any). and obviously, he still wants to have `.0`

Comment: @Azeez Kallayi : The answer provided by you will do fine, since I am working with only two decimals. In the example I provided, it covers the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a simple function to help you out with that. Something like this could do the trick:

```
<?php

    function removeTrailingZero($num){
        $num    = floatval($num);
        $pieces = explode(".", $num);
        for($i=0; $i<count($pieces); $i++){
            if(isset($pieces[1])){
                $pieces[1] = preg_replace("#0*$#", "", $pieces[1]);
                break;
            }else{
                $pieces[1]  = '0';
                break;
            }
        }
        return rtrim(implode(".", $pieces), ".");
        //return floatval(rtrim(implode(".", $pieces), "."));
    }

    var_dump(removeTrailingZero(123.45));
    var_dump(removeTrailingZero(67.80));
    var_dump(removeTrailingZero(90));
    var_dump(removeTrailingZero(100.00000));

    // PRODUCES:::
    string '123.45'    (length=6)
    string '67.8'      (length=4)
    string '90.0'      (length=4)
    string '100.0'     (length=5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I need 100.0 instead of 100. I can edit your code for my requirement.

Comment: It's simple. Just add an else clause in the conditional `if` within the `for` Loop and then assign "0" to the `$pieces[1]` variable. Post is now updated to take that into consideration. However, you now risk getting `STRING` as the return data-type for that function...